# QTableWidget extremely slow while loading only a few items (< 10 items)

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtableview, qtablewidget

**Context:**

For an application, I am creating a minified 'file browser' that shows the file icon, file name, relative location (w.r.t. a specific directory), date & size including folders.

**Problem:**

I am using the "convinience" `QTableWidget` for displaying of the file entries, however while testing on a few files (<10 folders / files), it takes ~3s to display the content.

After calling [QTableWidget::setItem(int, int, QTableWidgetItem*)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem) for each column, I would expect the UI to update and show the item.

What actually happens is all items are processed (`setItem(int, int,  QTableWidgetItem*)` called then after some arbitrary time ~3s (depending on the number of items) it finally displays. **This is a problem!**

**What have I tried / Suggestions:**

- According to numerous posts (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031168/qtableview-is-extremely-slow-even-for-only-3000-rows)), resizing the `QHeaderView` on each insert is a big performance killer. I do not do this, instead I predefine the column widths on launch in the [QDialog::showEvent(QShowEvent*)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#showEvent)
- Another suggestion ([here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46719-Slow-loading-of-data-into-QTableWidget?p=211063#post211063) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20809825/4628115)) is to predefine the number of rows you will use using [QTableWidget::setRowCount(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setRowCount). I have done this by default.

**Using a Custom Table Model**

Finally,  it is [suggested](https://forum.qt.io/topic/50651/qtablewidget-very-slow/2) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4035953/4628115)) to rather use a [custom table model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) with a [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), with an example(s) found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html)

I am hesitant to take this approach (which appears to be the ideal one) as the fact that waiting ~3s for a few items to be shown in a [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) is absolutely absurd.

Any suggestions to improve performance would be greatly appreciated!

*I noticed that using a `QFuture` dramatically slows down performance vs a simple `foreach` loop, the latter being ~2-5 times faster, however the delay on the `QTableWidget` is still the main problem*

**Implementation details:**

UI Settings

```
QTableWidget Settings (UI)

    QObject
     - mouseTracking enabled
     - contextMenuPolicy: Custom
     - custom stylesheet
    
    QAbstractScrollArea:
     - horizontalScrollBar: AlwaysOff
    
    QAbstractItemView:
     - No triggers
     - No drag drop overwrite
     - Alternating row colours
     - selection mode: single
     - selection behaviour: select rows
     - icon size: 64x64
    
    QTableWidget:
     - show grid: no
     - gridStyle: nopen
     - sortingEnabled: true
    
    QTableWidget:
     - columnCount: 5
    
    Header:
     - horizontalHeaderShowSortIndicator: true
     - verticalHeaderVisible: false
     - verticalHeaderSectionSize: 64
```

**Custom Model Struct**

```
struct Model {
     int index = -1;
     QIcon* icon;
     QString* name;
     QString* location;
     QString* dateModified;
     QString* size;
     bool isDir = false;
}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Model);
```

**Preparing to add entries**

```
      //QFileInfoList list;  - all QFileInfo entries in the current directory
      ui->customTableWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
      ui->customTableWidget->setRowCount(list.size());

      connect(&futureWatcherLoadDirectory, &QFutureWatcher<QPair<QFileInfo, Model>>::finished, this, [this]() {
           loadDirectoryWaitCondition.wakeAll();
           futureWatcherLoadDirectory.disconnect();
           ui->customTableWidget->setEnabled(true);
           ui->customTableWidget->setSortingEnabled(true);

      });
      connect(&futureWatcherLoadDirectory, &QFutureWatcher<QPair<QFileInfo, Model>>::resultReadyAt, this, [&](int index) {
           if (ui->customTableWidget->rowCount() == 0) {
                Global::clearAndDeleteTableListWidget(ui->customTableWidget);
           }
           QPair<QFileInfo, Model> result = futureWatcherLoadDirectory.resultAt(index);
           currentDirectoryModel.append(&result.second);
           addTableEntry(&result.second);
           //publish to table
      });

      std::function<QPair<QFileInfo, Model>(const QFileInfo)> processFileInfoItem = [this](const QFileInfo fi) {
           return processFileInfoEntry(fi);
      };
      futureLoadDirectory = QtConcurrent::mapped(list, processFileInfoItem);

      futureWatcherLoadDirectory.setFuture(futureLoadDirectory);
```

**Adding entry item**

```
void ExplorerDialog::addTableEntry(Model* model)
{
     bool hasIcon = (model->icon != nullptr);
     QTableWidgetItem* iconItem = new QTableWidgetItem(hasIcon ? *model->icon : QIcon(), QString());
     QTableWidgetItem* nameItem = new QTableWidgetItem(*model->name);
     QTableWidgetItem* locationItem = new QTableWidgetItem(*model->location);
     QTableWidgetItem* dateModifiedItem = new QTableWidgetItem(*model->dateModified);
     QTableWidgetItem* sizeItem = new QTableWidgetItem(*model->size);

     if (hasIcon) {
          iconItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
     }
     nameItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
     locationItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
     dateModifiedItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
     sizeItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);

     if (!model->isDir && hasIcon) {
          QString base64 = ImageHelper::getIconBase64(*model->icon);
          QString html = QString("<img src='data:image/%1;base64, %2'>").arg(ImageHelper::getCacheImageFormat().toUpper(), base64);
          if (hasIcon) {
               iconItem->setToolTip(html);
          }
          nameItem->setToolTip(html);
          locationItem->setToolTip(html);
          dateModifiedItem->setToolTip(html);
          sizeItem->setToolTip(html);
     }

     int index = model->index;
     ui->customTableWidget->setItem(index, 0, iconItem);
     ui->customTableWidget->setItem(index, 1, nameItem);
     ui->customTableWidget->setItem(index, 2, locationItem);
     ui->customTableWidget->setItem(index, 3, dateModifiedItem);
     ui->customTableWidget->setItem(index, 4, sizeItem);

     // with or without QTableWidget::update being called, it has no effect. The item is not added to the table immediately (or almost immediately)
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a [`QFileSystemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) and either a [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) or [`QTreeView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html)?  Any extra display/interaction functionality you require can probably(?) be implemented using a custom item delegate.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for the suggestion - I have been meaning to use a better format, however I am more curious about the 'delay' that QTableWidget causes.

Comment: I would suggest to simplify your example. Remove everything that is irrelevant (`QFuture`, `QAbstractItemView`, `QAbstractScrollArea`, ...). You could also use fixed dummy data, which makes your example better reproducible. see [mcve]. You could also try if the icon is the culprit.

Comment: It's a known fact that `Widget` classes are more convenient to use but they take a performance hit when they have to deal with complex widgets as their item widgets, so the recommendation is to use `View` classes. With that being said, I don't see how <10 items should cause a problem. Try to do the same with a `QTreeWidget` and see if you're having the same issue. From my experience `QTreeWidget` has been the easiest to deal with.